# oracle apex tabular form select list with two different sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a tabular form based on a table - `link` . One of the columns in the tabular form is a select list which is based on the following query:

```
 select head,code 
 from chart
```

However, if the table `link` already contains column value of `code` from table `chart`, then the select list should not list that item.

When I do this with `not exist` keyword, it replaces existing records in link column with the select list query which is probably not in the table `link`.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated based on requirements.

In your tabular form query, have a case statement for the select list as follows:

```
SELECT colx,
       coly,
       ...
       case when code is not null then code 
            else APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY(1, code, 'SELECT head, code FROM chart', ,'YES', null)
       end AS code
FROM link
```

This will display the original code if the field is not null, else will display the select list of values from the chart table.

Comment: I think my question is not clear. The problem is existing tabular form values must not be replaced by select list value.select list values does not contain existing tabular form values. But it replaces the existing tabular form values with a non matching value since there is no common value between existing record and select  list query.

Comment: So basically if the field in the tabular form is not null then you want to keep the existing value, else you want to provide a select list?

Comment: Updated my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

am not exactly understand your question. HOPE IT WILL HELP YOU

```
select head,code from chart WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT code  from link);
```